# What are workouts that I can do at home instead of walking outside?

Tags: workout, walking

I don't walk and even when I plan to walk I just say I will do that tomorrow and I don't. So I say to myself I should try something at home. I don't want to buy anything, do you know any workouts that I can do easily at home and can benefit me as good as walking? I need to lose weight and get my stomach fit.

If you know any good website (even if I should pay) to see good workouts at home, please tell me about it.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need motivation as well as a workout plan, there are several of those, my favs are dailyburn.com and dailymile.com

Answer (score 4):

You can try [You Are Your Own Gym by Mark Lauren Body Weight Exercise](http://marklauren.com) at home and you don't need to buy any gym tools.

You can start exercising [it](http://marklauren.com) by doing ladders easily first then gradually getting better and better after you're used to its muscular endurance practice.

I got my core fitter/tighter by doing this. I couldn't lift my body to do just one push up a year ago, last night I just realised I can do classic push up correctly for 60 times and the total is apparently growing as long as I practice it dilligently. I'm also used to lunges and squats nowadays to make my feet stronger and I'm happy :-)

I do this exercise when I'm worried it's gonna rain on the road if I walk/jog outside.

Answer (score 3):

Running, jumping jacks, lunges, burpies, mountain climbers, squats, situps

Comment: Can you add some more context and information to your answer? What makes these exercises a good replacement for walking outside: does it work out all the same muscles, effect heart rate the same, etc?